# Valgrind memory leak pointer

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have this function in order to expand the size of my char **array that I use in two other functions, which is why I'm passing it in by reference. I know I'm supposed to delete array at some point because it's dynamically allocated in this function, but I cant delete it until after I'm done using it in my code. However, valgrind still says memory is definitely lost in the line which contains array = new char *[cap2]. How should I go about deleting this?

```
void expand(int &size2, int &cap2, char **&array){
    int i;
    if(size2 ==1)
    {
            cap2 = size2;
            cap2 = cap2*2;
            array = new char*[cap2];
            for(int n=0; n<cap2; n++)
            {
                    array[n] = '\0';
            }
    }
    else{
            cap2 = cap2 *2;
            char **temp;
            temp = array;
            array = new char*[cap2];
            for(i =0; i<size2 ; ++i)
            {
                    array[i] = temp[i];
            }
            for(int k = size2; k<cap2; k++)
            {
                    array[k] = '\0';
            }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you just use `std::vector` you avoid all that hassle.

Comment: I second @stefan's comment. The STL libraries have been standard for a long time, and the `<vector>` header is used everywhere. you can just use `push_back( element )` and let the libraries handle allocation and deallocation for you.

Comment: @stefan The thing is I'm using execvp syscall, so at one point im calling execvp(array[0], array).

Comment: @NC Still possible. `execvp(array[0], &array[0])`.

Comment: @stefan Problem solved, thank you! One more question regarding execvp. If I've made a 2d vector `std::vector<std::vector<char *>> token(200)`, in order to pass in the first command would I do: `execvp(token[0][0], &token[0][0])` ?